# How can I reverse loop over a map by value?

Tags: c++, c++17

I need to get the pairs of the map sorted by its values, i wonder if it is posible without an temporal declaration.
I know i can sort it if i make another map with the keys and values swaped, but i am searching for a better solution.
I can't sort the elements afterwards because i only need extract the chars and put them on an array for example.

```
std::map<char,int> list = {{'A',4},{'V',2},{'N',1},{'J',5},{'G',3}};

for(/* code here */){
 std::cout << /* code here */ << std::endl;
}
```

Desired outout:

```
J 5
A 4
G 3
V 2
N 1
```

Comment: "i wonder if it is posible without an temporal declaration." - it's not, so stop wondering. A `std::map` has *one* ordering

Comment: One issue is that a `std::map` is optimized for searches by key.  Usually keys are unique, but values may not be.   A value may be associated with more than one key.

Comment: Add the pair `{'K', 2}` to your map and see what happens.  What do you want to happen?

Comment: @TomásMates If any different keys had any repeated values It wont matter the order, it would output the keys in any order, 'K' would be before or after 'V'.

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't wont to sort the map, just output the keys in a certain order.

Comment: why are you searching for a "better" solution? Whats wrong with the solution you know? What is "better"?

Comment: why are you not using a `std::map<int,char>` ? If you use a `std::vector<std::pair<int,char>>` then you can sort both ways

Comment: You realize "a certain order" is by-definition "sorted", right ?

Comment: @WhozCraig General piece of advice, you should avoid comments in the form of "you do know [X] right?" and instead use statements like "note that [X]". The first form can come across as rude or patronizing, as it implies that it is hard to believe that they wouldn't already know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done with [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

This template has an optional template argument which allows for a custom sorting, but this sorting can only be done on the map's key:

> ```cpp
> template<
>    class Key,
>    class T,
>    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
>    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> > class map;
> ```
>
> std::map is a sorted associative container that contains key-value pairs with unique keys. **Keys are sorted by using the comparison function `Compare`**.

This choice has been done as to not impose the map's value to be an orderable type.

---

As an alternative, you can use type `std::vector<std::pair<char, int>>` in combination with [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<char,int>> list = {{'A',4},{'V',2},{'N',1},{'J',5},{'G',3}};
    std::sort(begin(list), end(list), [](auto lhs, auto rhs) {
        return lhs.second > rhs.second ? true : ( rhs.first > rhs.first );
    });
    
    for(auto const& pair : list) {
        std::cout << pair.first << ", " << pair.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

> J, 5
> A, 4
> G, 3
> V, 2
> N, 1

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8bdfedcf74b60841)

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate solution depends on HOW are you going to use that `list`. Is it created once and queried once? Then anything will do: you can just sort the output.

However, if this is a "live" `list` that is constantly updated, and you need to query it frequently, I would suggest to keep another map of values to vector of keys. Then you would be able to get your result instantly. At a cost
of more expensive insertion, of course.